# Add noindex to single category in Magento 1.9

Tags: category, url, index

I want to modify this line for only one category:

```
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
```

I want to add noindex like this:

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW" />
```

I tried to add this code to Custom Layout Update in Custom Design tab of category:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
 </reference>
```

the result doesn't change.

This is an example of what i have done:

[image]

This solution doesn't work.

Comment: just tested it on fresh magento 1.9.1.0 install. worked. you probably have an extension that prevents it from working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code snippet on the default view if your content is on another store view.